# how install caffe for all system users?

Tags: python, bash, caffe, pycaffe

I installed caffe with anaconda in my home directory and it works.
Now I want that also the other system users can use caffe and run it using the python wrapper.
Thus, I first installed anaconda in `/opt/anaconda` and added this folder in the PATH variable in `/etc/bash.bashrc` (in a similar way I did with my `.bashrc` file). Then I copied my caffe directory to `/opt/caffe` and added the proper path in the PYTHONPATH variable in `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

As result, if another user runs python he correctly uses the anaconda version. Moreover he can run `import caffe`, but when it does so, an error is obtained because the python wrapper doesn t find the protobuf library.

I though that all the requirements have been installed for all the users and not just for me.
How can I correctly permit other users to run caffe using the copy in `/opt/caffe`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: run `make ditribute` and get a folder `$CAFFE_ROOT/distribute` this is all you need to run caffe. copy that and add that to the appropriate paths

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I copied the distribute folder in /opt and changed the PYTHONPATH in the bash.bashrc file, but it is still no working when logged with other users.... when I run import caffe it doesn't find the module google.protobuf.internal... I've also run "pip install protobuf" logged with the other user but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer for those who've compiled Caffe up to `make distribute` and went for extra style points with `make pycaffe`. I am proud of you. Now you would like to let all users of your Debian-based OS `import caffe` from Python successfully (e.g. avoiding the `cannot find libcaffe.so` errors upon import). I respect that.

[This GH Issue](https://github.com/dapperfu/build_caffe/issues/2#issue-354983064) has the answer. **make sure that you adapt the ABSOLUTE caffe path to your particular installation**:

```
echo <YOUR_CAFFE_ABSPATH>/distribute/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/caffe.conf
ldconfig
```

And for the Python wrapper, the package also has to be added to `PYTHONPATH`. You can do this by extending said path, or by copying the package into an already existing path, in my case as follows:

```
cp -r <YOUR_CAFFE_ABSPATH>/distribute/python/caffe /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

That's it! Now `import caffe` should work at any location.

---

Disclaimers:

- I've tested it on a GPU-compatible Ubuntu18 Docker image (this one nvcr.io/nvidia/cuda:11.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu18.04) as root
- I'm answering here because it is one of the top-ranked Google results for "install caffe for all users" and the GH issue isn't, so hopefully this helps someone!

I'd also be happy to hear from other solutions or remarks to make our Caffe life easier.
Cheers,
Andres